# RxJava combining observables without repeating execution

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Short story:
I have a situation where I have 2 Observables that have a single purpose:

- they receive some data
- they return modified data
- throw an error if the data cannot be processed

They are each in charge of handling different types of data. Additionally I want to do something when both data has been processed.

My current best implementation is as follows, these are my Observables:

```
    Single<BlueData> blueObservable = Single.create(singleSubscriber -> {
        if (BlueDataProcessor.isDataValid(myBlueData)) {
            singleSubscriber.onSuccess(BlueDataProcessor.process(myBlueData));
        }
        else {
            singleSubscriber.onError(new BlueDataIsInvalidThrow());
        }
    });

    Single<RedData> redObservable = Single.create(singleSubscriber -> {
        if (RedDataProcessor.isDataValid(myRedData)) {
            singleSubscriber.onSuccess(RedDataProcessor.process(myRedData));
        }
        else {
            singleSubscriber.onError(new RedDataIsInvalidThrowable());
        }
    });

    Single<PurpleData> composedSingle = Single.zip(blueObservable, redObservable,
            (blueData, redData) -> PurpleGenerator.combine(blueData, redData));
```

I also have the following subscriptions:

```
    blueObservable.subscribe(
            result -> {
                saveBlueProcessStats(result);
            },
            throwable -> {
                logError(throwable);
            });

    redObservable.subscribe(
            result -> {
                saveRedProcessStats(result);
            },
            throwable -> {
                logError(throwable);
            });


    composedSingle.subscribe(
            combinedResult -> {
                savePurpleProcessStats(combinedResult)
            },
            throwable -> {
                logError(throwable);
            });
```

MY PROBLEM:
The blue & red data is processed twice, because both subscriptions are run again with I subscribe to the combined observable created with Observable.zip().

How can I have this behaviour without running both operations twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `Single` in 1.x because there is no notion of a `ConnectableSingle` and thus `Single.publish`. You can achieve the effect via 2.x and the RxJava2Extensions library:

```
SingleSubject<RedType> red = SingleSubject.create();
SingleSubject<BlueType> blue = SingleSubject.create();

// subscribe interested parties
red.subscribe(...);
blue.subscribe(...);

Single.zip(red, blue, (r, b) -> ...).subscribe(...);

// connect()
blueObservable.subscribe(blue);
redObservable.subscribe(red);
```

Comment: I will implement this solution as soon as I can upgrade this project to rxjava2. However i'm happy enough with this solution to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!